# Resizing of graphic node in TitledPane's header

Tags: java, layout, resize, javafx-2

I think JavaFX's TitledPane shows a wrong resizing behavior when using a graphic node in its header. For when I add a `BorderPane` instance as a graphic (using `Label#setGraphic`) to a *label* and when I have set `contentDisplay` to `GRAPHIC_ONLY` then the `BorderPane` instance always occupies the complete interior of the label.
When I do the same, in contrast, with a *TitledPane* then the BorderPane ignores the actual size of the TitledPane's header but always uses its preferred width and height.
I would have expect that Label and TitledPane show the same resizing behavior as they are both subclasses of the same superclass Labeled. (Although, certainly `TitledPane` additionally has somehow to deal with the extra arrow-button.)

The following small program demonstrates the different layout behavior of TitledPane and Label.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.LabelBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPaneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPaneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LayoutProblem extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TitledPane tPane = TitledPaneBuilder.create().graphic(
                BorderPaneBuilder.create().prefHeight(20).prefWidth(100)
                .style("-fx-border-color: black;").build()
            ).contentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY)
                .maxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE).build();

        Label label = LabelBuilder.create().graphic(
                BorderPaneBuilder.create().prefHeight(20).prefWidth(100)
                .style("-fx-border-color: black;").build()
            ).contentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY)
            .maxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE).build();

        VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(tPane, label);
        vBox.setPrefWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

How can I manage the `BorderPane` instance to occupy the complete free space within the TitlePane's header (preferably taking the arrow-button into account)?

It might be possible to use css-lookup and write some width-property binding stunts but I think there should be a more convenient solution.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of titledpane with borderpane graphic, to imagine the problem visually? Try playing with insets and paddings of build-in css selector `.titled-pane > .title`.

Comment: I've tried to add a screenshot. Unfortunately, I need 10 reputations for posting a picture. However, I have added some code.